# Не работает NPM

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, npm

Установил node.js из пакета `nodejs-legacy` и npm из `npm`. Но при запуске `node -v`, перед выводом версии вылетает вот такая ошибка

> ```
> node: /home/mr-blaze/.linuxbrew/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version 
> information available (required by node)
> node: /home/mr-blaze/.linuxbrew/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version 
> information available (required by node)
> node: /home/mr-blaze/.linuxbrew/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version 
> information available (required by node)
> node: /home/mr-blaze/.linuxbrew/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version 
> information available (required by node)
> v4.2.6
> ```

, а при `npm -v` вылетает

> ```
> /usr/bin/nodejs: /home/mr-blaze/.linuxbrew/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no         
> version information available (required by /usr/bin/nodejs)
> /usr/bin/nodejs: /home/mr-blaze/.linuxbrew/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no     
> version information available (required by /usr/bin/nodejs)
> /usr/bin/nodejs: /home/mr-blaze/.linuxbrew/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no 
> version information available (required by /usr/bin/nodejs)
> /usr/bin/nodejs: /home/mr-blaze/.linuxbrew/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no 
> version information available (required by /usr/bin/nodejs)
> ../src/node_crypto.cc:5426: void node::crypto::InitCryptoOnce(): 
> Assertion `(sk_num(((_STACK*) (1 ? (comp_methods) : (struct 
> stack_st_SSL_COMP*)0)))) == (0)' failed.
> Аварийный останов (сделан дамп памяти)
> ```

и ничего не происходит! Пытался гуглить, но тщетно!

Ubuntu 16.04 x64

Прошу вашей помощи!

Comment: Сообщения об ошибках - пожалуйста, непосредственно в вопрос. А то сейчас возникает полное впечатление, что ошибка при запуске `node -v` звучит как "Файлы без расширений недоступны для предпросмотра!".

Comment: @yaant благодарю за замечание! исправил

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что в libssl для Ubuntu есть несколько дополнительных изменений, которых нет в libssl, в вашем случае, для linuxbrew. Одним из таких изменений является **информация о версии**, поэтому вы видите сообщение `no version information available`.

Как вариант, можно заменить файл libssl для linuxbrew на ссылку файла, установленного для Ubuntu, который уже имеет в себе информацию о версии:

```bsh
locate libssl.so.1.0.0
sudo rm /home/mr-blaze/.linuxbrew/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 /home/mr-blaze/.linuxbrew/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
```

Аналогично с libcrypto:

```bsh
locate libcrypto.so.1.0.0
sudo rm /home/mr-blaze/.linuxbrew/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /home/mr-blaze/.linuxbrew/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте немного пояснений к коду. Так будет намного информативнее, почему происходит ошибка и как именно этот код её устраняет.

Answer (score 0):

Последняя версия nodejs 12 (рекомендуемая 10), а какая в репозитория убунты страшно даже представить, так что ничего удивительного.

Ставьте [актуальную версию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/868763/node-js-%D0%BD%D0%B0-ubuntu-16-04/).