# node js на Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu

Установил Node js. посмотрел версию, 8.10....Возможно ли обновить Node до 8.11.3? Если да, то как?

Comment: как установили? `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade nodejs` не помогает. Посмотреть у на одном из серверов 16.04 LTS, стоит 8.11.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs build-essential
```

Comment: Вместо `setup_10.x` укажите `setup_8.x`, если нужно.

Comment: Дополню, что на данный момент можно указывать `setup_11.x`, сейчас это самая новая версия